# Declaring a list in java, best practice

Tags: java, list, collections

I've come across a question of best practice. Which option is better:

`List list = new ArrayList<String>();`

or

`List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`
?

Is there any down side of using any of these? Or writing `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>()`;

Comment: The first should result in a compiler warning about using raw types, don't do that. Number 3 used to be the way to do it until the shorthand version (number 2) was introduced in java 8 (or java7?), so use either of these.

Comment: `List list` is *raw type*. Please see [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321)

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
List <String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Or:

```
List <String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Both are correct.

Comment: You should give more explanation about the reasons.